# Unique indexing of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have to merge data from several excel file and make a data frame. When i do that the index of the rows in the dataframes are not unique as shown below,

```
    a
0  green
1  blue
2  red
0  orange
1  black
2  yellow
```

Here i am trying to merge 2 different excel files. One with the data green,blue,red and another one with orange,black,yellow. The index are repeating themselves, which is not what i want. I want them to be unique like the example below,

```
     a      
0  green
1  blue
2  red
3  orange
4  black
5  yellow
```

How do i do that with pandas?

Comment: The first one is the same as the second one.

Comment: hi, sorry..my bad..just editted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your final `dataframe` you can do:

```
In [6]: df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[6]:
        a
0   green
1    blue
2     red
3  orange
4   black
5  yellow
```

Comment: Here you either need to assign it back (`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`) or need to pass inplace=True (`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`).

Answer (score 2):

If you were merging your Excel files using `concat()` function, then use `ignore_index=True` parameter like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

so you won't need to reset index later on